# BUILD FAILED in 10m 18s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

The errors show when I try to run the code

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10m 18s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is the error that keeps showing,

Things that I have tried;
1. I have done the flutter upgrade
2. I have done the packages upgrade
3. invalidated the caches on Android studio

This errors is showing on Android studio IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same issue before, it's happening because of the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image#-readme-tab-) package. You have to use the **2.0.0-rc** version of cached_network_image to fix the issue.

You can find more details here: [Issue 270](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/270)

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful